# How to combine Lwt filters?

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml, lwt

I am currently learning [Lwt](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/2.4.7/manual). I am interested into using asynchronous processes to replace some shell routines by OCaml routines.

Let us take a look at a simplified first attempt, where a filter is created by combining two threads running `cat`:

```
let filter_cat ()=
  Lwt_process.pmap_lines ("cat", [| "cat" |])

let filter_t () =
  Lwt_io.stdin
  |> Lwt_io.read_lines
  |> filter_cat ()
  |> filter_cat ()
  |> Lwt_io.write_lines Lwt_io.stdout

let () =
  filter_t ()
  |> Lwt_main.run
```

This filter somehow works but hangs up when its standard input closes instead of exiting.  If I remove one of the `filter_cat`, it works as expected.

I am guessing that I do not compose these filters appropriately and therefore cannot *join* the two threads I am starting. What is the correct way to compose these filters, so that the program terminates after it reads `EOF` on `stdin`?

---

You can find this program together with a [BSD Owl](https://github.com/michipili) Makefile in a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/michipili/28d2358978d9e3c4bcef).

Comment: No idea why it's not working; sorry I can't help about that, maybe try the ocsigen mailing-list. On the stylistic side, I find the definition of `filter_cat` very confusing. Writing `let filter_cat strm = ...` and then `|> filter_cat` would be clearer.

Comment: Also, `Lwt_main.run (filter_t ())` would be a lot clearer than `filter_t () |> Lwt_main.run` because `Lwt_main.run` is not a filter by any reasonable definition of the term.

Comment: @MartinJambon Hi Martin, thanks for your hints and tips! I will ask on the mailing list.

Comment: @MartinJambon For the record I opened an [issue describing that behaviour](https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/issues/137).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this, is that there is a little bug in Lwt.  There is an internal function, [monitor](https://github.com/ocsigen/lwt/blob/master/src/unix/lwt_process.ml#L412) that which performs the piping:

```
(* Monitor the thread [sender] in the stream [st] so write errors are
   reported. *)
let monitor sender st =
  let sender = sender >|= fun () -> None in
  let state = ref Init in
  Lwt_stream.from
    (fun () ->
       match !state with
         | Init ->
             let getter = Lwt.apply Lwt_stream.get st in
             let result _ =
               match Lwt.state sender with
                 | Lwt.Sleep ->
                     (* The sender is still sleeping, behave as the
                        getter. *)
                     getter
                 | Lwt.Return _ ->
                     (* The sender terminated successfully, we are
                        done monitoring it. *)
                     state := Done;
                     getter
                 | Lwt.Fail _ ->
                     (* The sender failed, behave as the sender for
                        this element and save current getter. *)
                     state := Save getter;
                     sender
             in
             Lwt.try_bind (fun () -> Lwt.choose [sender; getter]) result result
         | Save t ->
             state := Done;
             t
         | Done ->
             Lwt_stream.get st)
```

The problem is in the definition

```
let getter = Lwt.apply Lwt_stream.get st
```

When the `getter` process meets the end of the stream, then it is saved, but the `sender` is lost, which seems to prevent completion. This can be fixed by improving the definition of `getter` by telling it to behave as the `sender` when the end of the stream has been reached.